# phpexcel save as pdf

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am testing phpexcel and need to save the file as a pdf, however I receive the following error:

TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get image: zip://pcash.xlsx#xl/media/image3.emf

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel2, 'PDF');
$objWriter->save('pcash1.pdf');
```

I have seen this thread, but don't really understand why the built in PDF writer apparently cannot create PDFs ??

[PHPExcel create/style/save PDF Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678566/phpexcel-create-style-save-pdf-documentation)

Is it not possible to save a file as pdf and if not why not as that appears to be a built in feature ??

Comment: If you look at the latest code in github develop branch, it allows a choice of PDF renderer (tcPDF, mPDF or DomPDF)... you could check if any of the other rendering engines would work with this file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the documentation for the tcPDF library, EMF format images are supported via the [ImageMagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) extension (if the extension is loaded in PHP) and on a Windows platform (apparently [ImageMagick only supports EMF on Windows platforms](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/formats.html)).